# Transferring wordpress from a hijacked domain name

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, localhost

I've read many questions on here but nothing seems to fit my scenario and try as I might, nothing seems to work so far!

My host unlawfully transferred my domain name out from under me resulting ine being unable to use the usual plugins to export my site and migrate it… Nominet enabled me to regain access to my domain name and I’ve transferred it out from 1&1 Ionos to a new host (GoDaddy) and went about setting up a hosting plan with them.

So, what I have is a webspace with Ionos with all the WordPress files and the database from my WordPress site which I’ve downloaded via FTP and my new domain name set up with a Linux server with GoDaddy.

The issue I’m facing is, when I upload the site files I downloaded via FTP and import the database, it keeps coming up with the “install WordPress” screen to set up a fresh WordPress site.

I’ve transferred over the htaccess file and now, it’s trying to download a file that doesn’t do anything (according to the text in the file when opened with notepad).

I’m in a right pickle. Wp-config is all set up correctly so far as I can tell pointing to the new host with the new database username and password.

Can anyone provide a step by step guide on moving from another server webspace to the domain name? All the guides online I can find includes migration whilst the previous site is still active. For me, this isn’t the case.

My issue is (probably) unique because it is effectively a local host set up on the 1and1 server where everything is still pointing to my domain name, I’ve downloaded this and assumed it wouldn’t be too difficult to just upload, reconnect the database and I’d be good to go but it doesn’t seem to be so easy as I expected.

So far, I’ve spent the last 8 hours toying with it myself, and since the 11th June dealing with the domain hijacking and spent much of that time with Ionos and GoDaddy support to try and get it all sorted and up and running… Its half 3 in the morning now and this post is probably going to be my last avenue for a solution before giving up on it!

Really appreciate the help.

Comment: You're paying GoDaddy. They can provide step-by-step instructions

Comment: It's "outside of scope" as far as they're concerned